# What is the right way to parse large amount of input for main function in C++

Tags: c++, xml, class, coding-style, program-entry-point

Suppose there are 30 numbers I had to input into an executable, because of the large amount of input, it is not reasonable to input them via command line. One standard way is to save them into a single XML file and use XML parser like tinyxml2 to parse them. The problem is if I use tinyxml2 to parse the input directly I will have a very bloated main function, which seems to [contradict](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85657/why-should-main-be-short/85670) the common good practice.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int a[30];      

  tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc_xml;

  if (doc_xml.LoadFile(argv[1])){
    std::cerr << "failed to load input file";
  }
  else {
    tinyxml2::XMLHandle xml(&doc_xml);

    tinyxml2::XMLHandle a0_xml =
        xml.FirstChildElement("INPUT").FirstChildElement("A0");

    if (a0_xml.ToElement()) {
      a0_xml.ToElement()->QueryIntText(&a[0]);
    }
    else {
      std::cerr << "A0 missing";
    }

    tinyxml2::XMLHandle a1_xml =
        xml.FirstChildElement("INPUT").FirstChildElement("A1");

    if (a1_xml.ToElement()) {
      a1_xml.ToElement()->QueryIntText(&a[1]);
    }
    else {
      std::cerr << "A1 missing";
    }

    // parsing all the way to A29 ... 
  }

  // do something with a

  return 0;
}
```

But on the other hand, if I write an extra class just to parse these specific type of input in order to shorten the main function, it doesn't seem to be right either, because this extra class will be useless unless it's used in conjunction with this main function since it can't be reused elsewhere.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int a[30];      

  ParseXMLJustForThisExeClass ParseXMLJustForThisExeClass_obj;

  ParseXMLJustForThisExeClass_obj.Run(argv[1], a);

  // do something with a

  return 0;
}
```

What is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: You seem to be suffering from not having enough experience to gauge the re-usability requirements of your code. For example, we can't offer suggestions about this kind of decision until you let us know what the data represents and what the application plans on doing with the data. For example, will the data be some sort of common file format that will be used by multiple applications in the future? If you provide this kind of information, I can tell you exactly want you need to know.

Comment: before it is reusable it has to got to be usable

Comment: @didiz Exactly... The OP worrying too much about this is the cause of his confusion. However, the best way for someone at this point to learn about where to draw that line is by having the re-usability requirements of their situation established by a more experienced programmer.

Comment: @rationalcoder This is obviously a very simplified example. In actuality it's not just 30 integers, it's a combination of images, extrinsic/intrinsic matrix parameters, boolean flags etc. Lets suppose some other executable E1 uses part of A like A0~A10 and B0~B5, executable E2 uses A5~A25. No other executable other than this one uses exactly A0~A29. Is this enough information for you to provide an answer?

Comment: That is enough information for me to know that there is almost certainly a design flaw with what the programs are expected to do. Apart from that, it is still just as unanswerable. What does the program do with that odd combination of input, and why does a completely different program take in a subset of that input? Why aren't they the same program?

Comment: @rationalcoder To give you a really dumbed down example. It's totally normal for a program to have two integer (A0~A1) as an input and the other program with one integer (A0) and one float (B0) as an input, right? This is certainly not a design flaw. Why should they be the same program?

Comment: Your right, that isn't a design flaw... It also doesn't sound anything like the programs you were outlining in your previous comment. With your comments so far, I am imagining some input that might warrant the use of XML, with one program taking it and operating on most of it and another taking in the same file and operating on a small part of it. I don't need a dumbed down example; I need a real world example...

Comment: One issue is re-usability. The other issues are readability and maintainability. That's why most of our "productive" applications have an `AppContext` class which is instanced only once in the `main()` function (as local variable i.e. on stack). The performance costs of the extra calls are neglectable but the development time will definitely shorten when code is easy to read and maintain. Costs of extra class instances or function calls should be considered only where performance is really an issue (e.g. code in the most inner run-time loop of a simulation).

Comment: Just a stab in the dark: are you just talking about the similarity between `./program1 <a few common numerical params> <non common params>` and `./program2 <common stuff> <non common params>` ?

Comment: @Scheff That isn't what this discussion is about, by the way. At this point, I am under the impression that he is just feeling the need to factor out the input of common arguments to programs.

Comment: I like more the 2nd approach of the OP (the way I would do it). Actually, I was just born when the [Software crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_crisis) happened. But everything, I learnt at university and use today was founded/invented as a result to overcome the Software Crisis.

Comment: @rationalcoder As I understood the question, it is: Is it worth to move code into an extra class which is only used once (in `main()`). If I'm wrong I will erase my comments with excuse...

Comment: Just another thought: It's difficult to ask the experienced programmer if you are yourself the (most) experienced programmer in company. In this case, the following rules help: 1. Make code usable for the 1st need. 2. If a 2nd (similar) need evolves adapt the code to become usable for both cases (if necessary). 3. Accept that code has to be modified again and again according to evolving new requirements. (The latter, I call code maintainance.)

Comment: @Scheff Oh, wow. I hope that wasn't his question. If it is, we could have an interesting flame war on our hands :) b/c I'm from the even newer age of realizing that OOP isn't a panacea and the best solution, depending on this guys actual use case, is likely a simple procedure.

Comment: @rationalcoder Meanwhile I followed his link [contradict](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85657/why-should-main-be-short/85670) and found (in the question) exactly what I said or intended to say. So, I'm not quite sure anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, besides reading XML files you can also pass lots of data through stdin. It's pretty common practice to use e.g. `mycomplexcmd | hexdump -C`, where `hexdump` is reading from stdin through the pipe.

Now up to the rest of the question: there's a reason to go with the your multiple-functions example *(here it's not very important whether they're constructors or usual functions)*. It's pretty much the same as why would you want any function to be smaller — readability. That said, I don't know about the "common good practice", and I've seen many terminal utilities with very big `main()`.

Imagine someone new is reading 1-st variant of `main()`. They'd be going through the hoops of figuring out all these handles, queries, children, parents — when all they wanted is to just look at the part after `// do something with a`. It's because they don't know if it's relevant to their problem or not. But in the 2-nd variant they'll quickly figure it out "Aha, it's the parsing logic, it's not what I am looking for".

That said, of course you can break the logic with detailed comments. But now imagine something went wrong, someone is debugging the code, and they pinned down the problem to this function *(alright, it's funny given the function is `main()`, maybe they just started debugging)*. The bug turned out to be very subtle, unclear, and one is checking everything in the function. Now, because you're dealing with mutable language, you'd often find yourself in situation where you think "oh, may be it's something with this variable, where it's being changed?"; and you first look up every use of the variable through this large function, then conditions that could lead to blocks where it's changed; then you figuring out what does this another big block, relevant to the condition, that could've been extracted to a separate function, what variables are used in there; and to the moment you figured out what it's doing you already forgot half of what you were looking before!

Of course sometimes big functions are unavoidable. But if you asked the question, it's probably not your case.

Rule of thumb: you see a function doing two different things having little in common, you want to break it to 2 separate functions. In your case it's parsing XML and "doing something with a". Though if that 2-nd part is a few lines, probably not worth extracting — speculate a bit. Don't worry about the overhead, compilers are good at optimizing. You can either use LTO, or you can declare a function in `.cpp` file only as static *(non-class static)*, and depending on optimization options a compiler may inline the code.

P.S.: you seem to be in the state where it's very useful to learn'n'play with some Haskell. You don't have to use it for real serious projects, but insights you'd get can be applied anywhere. It forces you into better design, in particular you'd quickly start feeling when it's necessary to break a function *(aside of many other things)*.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. What do you think about moving the parsing code to a free function in main.cpp? Does this approach get the best of both variants?

Comment: @user3667089 that's what I'd do because it'd result in less code as compared to a class. Class is an abstraction, abstract when necessary. You wouldn't want to create a class for every single step in a code, would you? Ask yourself: why do you need class? Do you need to group some members? Does it make your code terser and more readable *(e.g. if you're inheriting from some other class, which is not always improves things)*? If you'd blindly throw abstractions here and there, it would not magically make your code better, there's no such a silver bullet.